# Green's Theorem and Divergence (2D)

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis, plane-curves

I am reading the book Numerical Solution of Partial Differential Equations by the Finite Element Method by Claes Johnson.

In Chapter 1 he talks about the Possion Equation, and to prove that FEM solves this, he starts by defining divergence:
$$\int_{\Omega} div(A)\; dx = \int_{\Omega} \frac{\partial A_1}{\partial x_1} +  \frac{\partial A_1}{\partial x_2} \; dx  =  \int_{\Gamma} A \cdot n \; ds$$

And says that if we apply this to A = (vw,0) and A = (0,vw) we get that:
$$\int_{\Omega} div(vw,0) \; dx = \int_{\Omega} \frac{\partial vw}{\partial x_1} + 0 \; dx = \int_{\Omega} \frac{\partial v}{\partial x_1}w \; dx + \int_{\Omega} \frac{\partial w}{\partial x_1} v \; dx = \int_{\Gamma} vw \cdot n_1 \; ds$$
$$\int_{\Omega} div(0,vw) \; dx =  0 + \int_{\Omega} \frac{\partial vw}{\partial x_2} \; dx = \int_{\Omega} \frac{\partial v}{\partial x_2}w \; dx + \int_{\Omega} \frac{\partial w}{\partial x_2} v \; dx = \int_{\Gamma} vw \cdot n_2 \; ds$$

These equations I follow and understand, but the next part is where I give up!
He defines the gradient as $\nabla v = \left( \frac{\partial v}{\partial x_1} +  \frac{\partial v}{\partial x_2} \right) $

And by using the two equations from above we can "see" that:
$$\int_{\Omega} \nabla v \cdot \nabla w \; dx \equiv \int_{\Omega} \left[ \frac{\partial v}{\partial x_1} \frac{\partial w}{\partial x_1} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial x_2} \frac{\partial w}{\partial x_2} \right] dx = \int_{\Gamma} \left[ v \frac{\partial w}{\partial x_1}n_1 + v \frac{\partial w}{\partial x_2}n_2 \right] ds - \int_{\Omega} v\left[ \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x_1^2} + \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x_2^2}  \right] dx$$

And it's this last equation that I simply can't figure out. I can see that the two gradients (vectors multiplied) gives the "congruent" with, but from here I'm lost!

Is there anyone who can give me a hint to how to use the theorem/equations from before??
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $\nabla v$ is a **vector**, not a scalar:
$$
\nabla v = \left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_1}, \frac{\partial v}{\partial x_2}\right)
$$

Now observe that:
\begin{align*}
div(v \nabla w)
&= div\left(v\frac{\partial w}{\partial x_1}, v\frac{\partial w}{\partial x_2}\right) \\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\left[  v\frac{\partial w}{\partial x_1} \right] + \frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}\left[  v\frac{\partial w}{\partial x_2} \right] \\
&= \left[\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_1}\frac{\partial w}{\partial x_1} + v\frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x_1^2} \right] + \left[\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_2}\frac{\partial w}{\partial x_2} + v\frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x_2^2} \right] \\
&= \left[\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_1}\frac{\partial w}{\partial x_1} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial x_2}\frac{\partial w}{\partial x_2} \right] + v\left[\frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x_1^2} + \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x_2^2} \right] \\
&= [\nabla v \cdot \nabla w] + v\left[\frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x_1^2} + \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x_2^2} \right] \\
\end{align*}

Hence, it follows that:
\begin{align*}
\int_{\Omega} \nabla v \cdot \nabla w \, dx
&= \int_{\Omega} \left( div(v \nabla w) - v\left[\frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x_1^2} + \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x_2^2} \right]\right) \, dx \\
&= \int_{\Omega} div(v \nabla w) \, dx - \int_{\Omega} v\left[\frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x_1^2} + \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x_2^2} \right] \, dx \\
&= \int_{\Gamma} (v \nabla w) \cdot n \, ds - \int_{\Omega} v\left[\frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x_1^2} + \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x_2^2} \right] \, dx \\
&= \int_{\Gamma} \left[ v \frac{\partial w}{\partial x_1}n_1 + v \frac{\partial w}{\partial x_2}n_2 \right] \, ds - \int_{\Omega} v\left[ \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x_1^2} + \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x_2^2}  \right] \, dx
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

The second to last integral is $\nabla w\cdot n$ so you go back with divergence theorem, and integrate the laplace.

$\nabla\cdot(v\nabla w)=v\Delta w+\nabla w\cdot\nabla v$

Thus:

$\int_{\Omega}\nabla w\cdot\nabla vdx=\int_{\Omega}\nabla\cdot(v\nabla w)dx-\int_\Omega v\Delta wdx=\int_{\partial\Omega=\Gamma}(v\nabla w)\cdot ndS(x)-\int_\Omega v\Delta wdx$